# String formatting: float without integer part

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to print a value into log file. My value is a float in range 0-1. The value needs to be formatted as 4 decimal digits, without integer part. So 0.42 will be printed as 4200, and with some text before.

This is my current approach:

```py
value = 0.42
print('my value is ' + f'{value:.4f}'[2:])
```

It somehow doesn't look very nice, so the question is: can I use float formatting in a way that I could avoid concatenating two string, something like:

```py
print(f'my value is {value:-1.4f}') # this looks nicer but doesn't do what I want
```

Comment: A bit offtopic: why do you want to do that? Your original code looks nice to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestions. To sum everything up, what I didn't like in my original solution is that its not clearly visible what its doing at the first glance.
I think slightly modified version posted by hiro protagonist is better:

```py
print(f'my value is {int(10000*value):04d}')
```

There is no need to split string + I need to add add '04d' to print leading zeros in case the number is smaller.

Answer (score 3):

this might work:

```
value = 0.42
print('my value is ' + f'{int(10000*value):4d}')
# my value is 4200
```

where i convert your `float` to an `int` first and the use integer formatting `:4d`.

or you may want to `round` first.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty good, you can leave it like it is. There's also other way, but I'm not sure that it's nice.

```
value = 0.42
print(f'my value is {str(value)[2:]:0<4}')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with contentation of `str`s to get argument for `print`, however if you are not allowed to do so, you can use following workaround:

```
value = 0.42
print('my value is',f'{value:.4f}'[2:])
```

Output:

```
my value is 4200
```

Note that I removed last space from `my values is` as `print` by default adds spaces between arguments it receive.